# Dart key value with different data type

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this key value pairs I wanted to send to the server :

```dart
String brand = "sony";

  double price_val = 0.01,
      ram_val = 0.01,
      internal_val = 0.01,
      kamera_val = 0.01;

var arguments = {
  "brand": brand,
  "price": price_val,
  "ram": ram_val,
  "internal": internal_val,
  "kamera": kamera_val
};
```

But i got this error :

```dart
Error : type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
```

If I changed it to `.toString()`, the server will give another error because the values need to be `double`.
How can I send exactly with those values?

**EDIT**

it looks like it gave an error on the http request :

```dart
http.post(url,
        body: arguments,
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}).then((onValue) {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => ResultPage(
                    onValue.body,
                  )));
});
```

Comment: What data type does `body` require on the `http.post`?

Comment: the data type on `http.post` are `String`

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html

Comment: thanks! I need to encode before send it to server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you set `application/json` as a content type in your request header, you need to encode your request body to json using `jsonEncode`

here are the example

```
http.post(url,
        body: jsonEncode(arguments),
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}).then((onValue) {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => ResultPage(
                    onValue.body,
                  )));
});
```

Comment: hey I know you!! aowkaowk

Answer (score 0):

Define the arguments type explicitly

```
final arguments = <String, Object>{
  "brand": brand,
  "price": price_val,
  "ram": ram_val,
  "internal": internal_val,
  "kamera": kamera_val
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dynamic keyword:

```
final arguments = <String, dynamic>{
  "brand": brand,
  "price": price_val,
  "ram": ram_val,
  "internal": internal_val,
  "kamera": kamera_val
};
```